# Promoting to Rook or Bishop

Tags: pawn-promotion

Is there  any chess position where the most correct move would be promoting a pawn on the 7th or 2nd rank to a Rook or Bishop since the queen can perform both their moves.

Comment: There are many endgame positions where under-promoting to a rook is done to avoid a stalemate.

Comment: I posted typical rook example. Bishops are usually quite academic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rook is typical this one:

W: Kh8 Re3, B:Kg4 Pf2

White to move can't hold.

Re4 Kg5 Re5 Kg6 Re6 Kf7 Re5! f1R!! (queening runs to Rf5 with stalemate). Rh5 Kg6  0-1